# Excel to check if comma separated value in cell contains allowed values in list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create an excel formula if comma-separated values in the cell doesn't present in the allowed values list then I need to highlight it.

Something like this

[image]

Is there any excel formula to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Conditional formatting rule applied to `=$B$3:$C$7`:

```
=ISERROR(SUM(MATCH(TEXTSPLIT(B3,","),H$4:H$7,0)))
```

Or, without `TEXTSPLIT()` but with `FILTERXML()`:

```
=ISERROR(SUM(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B3,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),H$4:H$7,0)))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have Excel 365 (current channel!) you can use this formula:

```vb
=BYROW(A2:A3,LAMBDA(d,
SUM(--ISERROR(FIND(TEXTSPLIT(d,,","),E2:E3)))=0
))
```

[image]

The formula splits - per row - the fruits - and tries to find the value in the allowed list. If found it will return a number, if not an error is returned.

Using -- true/false are converted to 1 and 0.

So that - if all values are found (= no errors) 0 is returned. If a value is not on the allowed list, an error is returned which will result in a sum value > 0.