# Apache POI Conditional formatting for comma separated values mismatch

Tags: java, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

I am trying to generate xlsx file with conditional formatting using apache.poi in java.  If comma-separated string values are not present, then in excel cell then I need to highlight red colour.

Something like this for reference

Here these are the **possible values ="TX,NC,AZ,CA"**, If anything other than these entered in cell. It should be highlighted. Entered value in excel can be single or comma-separated as well.

[image]

```
            String possiblevalues ="TX,NC,AZ,CA";
            
            ConditionalFormattingRule rule11 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(<<>>);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FontFormatting font11 = rule11.createFontFormatting();
            font11.setFontStyle(false, true);
            font11.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.RED.index);
            String cellrangeadd1 = "A4:A100";
            CellRangeAddress[] regions1 = new CellRangeAddress[] { CellRangeAddress.valueOf(cellrangeadd1) };
            sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions1, rule11);
```

Is there any conditional formatting rule to compare and validate from comma separated string value ?

Comment: How would you do it in Excel? If you do it in Excel, save the file as XLSX and unzip the file, how did Excel encode it?

Comment: in excel I did it manually with these test data and colored to red for reference. I am looking for a solution using conditional formatting in java

Comment: Save the file from Excel which is doing it right, then rename `.xlsx` to `.zip` and unzip, then check what Excel did. That will guide you to what you need to do in Apache POI

Comment: Actually, i am trying to generate xlsx file from java

Comment: In order to see what you need to tell Apache POI to do, often the easiest way is to see what Excel itself does. So follow my advice above and do that!

Comment: Thanks Gargavar will check on that.. FYI This excel formula worked =ISERROR(SUM(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B3,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),H$4:H$7,0)))  but trying to translate that into java code that's where i got stuck. For reference ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362810/excel-to-check-if-comma-separated-value-in-cell-contains-allowed-values-in-list/74363109#74363109 )

Comment: Do you want to save a conditional format inside excel (so that it changes dynamically when you manually change the data) or do you want to format the sheet in Java depending on the values that are filled in the cells at the time of creation, but the formatting doesn't change when you change the value in Excel?

Comment: @cyberbrain  Yes..conditional format inside excel (so that it changes dynamically when you manually change the data).     I am creating this excel in java by including conditional format as well.  So in the generated excel,if someone  enter a incorrect value it should be highlighted be in RED.